# Lifecycle Callbacks not triggering in my embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

It would appear my lifecycle callbacks are not triggered when the form to upload my file is embedded in another form. If the upload form is on its own the lifecycle callbacks are triggered.

I have a form that creates a 'user' entity, for this user I have a one-on-one relationship with the 'ProfilePicture' entity which has the lifecycle callbacks, I want to upload the profilepicture file on the same form. I followed the "How to handle File Uploads" cookbook, but it doesn't explain how to handle embedded forms.

**UserType**

```
<?php
namespace CashBack\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /* additional fields that should not be saved in this object need ->add('agreeWithTerms', null,array('mapped' => false))*/
        $builder
            ->add('id','hidden',array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('gender')
            ->add('dateOfBirth','birthday')
            ->add('customrole')
            ->add('profilepicture', new ProfilePictureType())
            ->add('save', 'submit');

    }
       /* Identifier */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'User';
    }
    /* Makes sure the form doesn't need to guess the date type */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true,

        ));
    }
}
```

**ProfilePictureType**

```
<?php
namespace CashBack\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProfilePictureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /* additional fields that should not be saved in this object need ->add('agreeWithTerms', null,array('mapped' => false))*/
        $builder
            ->add('id','hidden',array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('file','file');


    }
    /* Identifier */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ProfilePicture';
    }
    /* Makes sure the form doesn't need to guess the date type */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture',
        ));
    }
}
```

**ProfilePicture Entity**

```
<?php
namespace CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ProfilePicture
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $temp;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename   = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->path = $filename . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return ProfilePicture
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profilepicture")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return ProfilePicture
     */
    public function setUser(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

**User Entity**

```
<?php
namespace CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FirstName", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="LastName", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Gender", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Email", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DateOfBirth", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dateofbirth;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Username", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Password", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_tag",
     *   joinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $tag;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Customrole", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_customrole",
     *   joinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customrole_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $customrole;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Shop", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_shop",
     *   joinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="Id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tag        = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->customrole = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->shop       = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set gender
     *
     * @param string $gender
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGender($gender)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gender
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateofbirth
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateofbirth
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDateofbirth($dateofbirth)
    {
        $this->dateofbirth = $dateofbirth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateofbirth
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateofbirth()
    {
        return $this->dateofbirth;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add tag
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addTag(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tag[] = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tag
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
     */
    public function removeTag(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tag->removeElement($tag);
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    /**
     * Add customrole
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Customrole $customrole
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addCustomrole(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Customrole $customrole)
    {
        $this->customrole[] = $customrole;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove customrole
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Customrole $customrole
     */
    public function removeCustomrole(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Customrole $customrole)
    {
        $this->customrole->removeElement($customrole);
    }

    /**
     * Get customrole
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCustomrole()
    {
        return $this->customrole;
    }

    /**
     * Add shop
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Shop $shop
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addShop(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Shop $shop)
    {
        $this->shop[] = $shop;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove shop
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Shop $shop
     */
    public function removeShop(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\Shop $shop)
    {
        $this->shop->removeElement($shop);
    }

    /**
     * Get shop
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ProfilePicture", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "all"}) */
    protected $profilepicture;


    /**
     * Set profilepicture
     *
     * @param \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture $profilepicture
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setProfilepicture(\CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture $profilepicture)
    {
        $this->profilepicture = $profilepicture;
        $profilepicture->setUser($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profilepicture
     *
     * @return \CashBack\DefaultBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture
     */
    public function getProfilepicture()
    {
        return $this->profilepicture;
    }

}
```

**User controller**

```
        //adds a new entity from data received via Ajax, no redirect
        public function addAjaxAction(Request $request)
        {

            $user = new User();

            $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $user = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            //prepare the response, e.g.
            $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
            //you can return result as JSON  , remember to 'use' Response!
            return new Response(json_encode($response));

        }
```

EDIT: when checking the profiler I saw that the following object is submitted in the form:
If i check the profiler I see the following object being submitted in the form: {"username":"test","password":"test","firstname":"test","lastname":"test","email":"test","gender":"t","dateOfBirth":{"month":"1","day":"1","year":"1902"},"customrole":["2"],"id":"","profilepicture":{"id":""},"_token":"YUDiZLi8dY6jtmEhZWk6ivnH3vsQIpnM_fxQ3ClJ2Gw"}

Profile picture is thus empty.

Comment: Your examples are missing how you actually ***persist*** the user and more importantly the `profilepicture` subproperty. Maybe that's not persisted at all? Did you check if the `$this->getFile()` returns anything other than null in your entity?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I added my user controller where I persist my user entity, I do not however persist the profilepicture seperate, I thought as it was a property of user this would have been taken care of automatically. So what I need to do is probably:
$profilepic = new ProfilePicture(); then 
$profilepicture = $user->getprofilepicture(); and persist that one seperately?
I also checked the profiler and added the submitted data as an edit to my post, basically profilepicture is empty when submitted.

Comment: I can not say for sure that you need to be explicit about persisting your profilepicture. You should give it a try. You can also solve such cases with LifeCycleCallbacks on your user entity, which would instantiate and set up a new profilepicture during prepersist or postpersist.